# Expanding a JS range/selection in an HTML textbox

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range, selection

Given a text box that a user has made a selection in, I would like to be able to expand the selection (by a word or character) with JS.

I know that in some browsers I can use `window.getSelection();` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.modify)) to get the current selection, and in FireFox you can use `selection.modify("extend", "forward", "word");` there is also a TextRange object that IE [supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This is a requirement as I need to inspect the selection and compare it to the text that comes before and after it (so obviously i will reset the selection when I am done).

I need to support IE9 (though maybe I can get away with IE10), Chrome and FF, and I have JQuery but can use any third party JS library.

This article is interesting, but not quite what  want: [Selection ranges in webkit (Safari/Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213961/selection-ranges-in-webkit-safari-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textareas have their own selection API that is different from the API for regular selections within the page or in `contenteditable` elements. It's pretty simple: a textarea has readable and writable `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties which represent the selection start and end positions respectively within the textarea's value. IE <= 8 had a different API for this but IE 9 supports it.

You don't get an equivalent of `Selection.modify()` but you may not need it anyway since it is generally easy enough to work with the textarea's value.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement

Answer (score 2):

You can change the active selection by:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
range.setStart(range.startContainer, 0); // set to the beginning
selection.setSingleRange(range);
```

Modifying the range wont update the UI, you have to set the range.

Comment: This looks like it will set the selection to the start only though? Regardless it doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/48d2Q/6/ In Chrome it errors with: Uncaught IndexSizeError: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.

Comment: You've not set up the jsFiddle properly. Make sure this code runs when you actually have a selection.