# How to get word on indicated location on WKWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webkit, wkwebview

When you long press a word on a WKWebView webpage, you will select it, and system will popup a menu to let you share/copy/lookup it so on. This is the iOS default behavior.

So my question is, **how do you programmatically get a word from indicated point (CGPoint) on the WKWebView webpage**?

Or, **how do you programmatically select a word on WKWebView webpage without long press**?

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at DOM Selection Range? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2214120/218152

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175224/get-word-under-tap-from-uiwebview-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

First you must convert the point to the scrollview's coordinate system using [convertPoint:toView:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622442-convertpoint?language=objc). You can use this point in a Javascript (with jQuery) function which will search the DOM node at this point:

```
function(inX, inY) {
    var theWindow = $(window);
    var theElement = document.elementFromPoint(
        inX - theWindow.scrollLeft(), inY - theWindow.scrollTop());

    return theElement == null ? null : theElement.textContent;
}
```

Comment: Not works for me. error from webView.evaluateJavaScript says $ is undefined. After I replace $(window) with window, it says scrollLeft is undefined.

Comment: So I edit the script to this: `var theElement = document.elementFromPoint(\(point.x), \(point.y)); theElement == null ? null : theElement.textContent;` Now it can gives some content for me on the `point`, but instead give me a word, it gives me a whole sentence, which is not what I expected.

Comment: You must include jQuery to get the $-expressions work.

Comment: hey, sorry, can you tell me how to add jquery in wkwebview? i can't make it.

Comment: You can load jQuery into a string and execute it with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript